# Getting error when deploying WebJob to Azure?

Tags: powershell, azure-webjobs, kudu

Im deploying a webjob to Azure App using the kudu zip push deployment for a web app in Powershell

I am using the following:

```
az login -u <username>
az account set --subscription <subscription_name>
az webapp deployment source config-zip -g <ResourecGroup> -n <WebAppName> --src <pathetozipfile>

but i keep getting the error:

"az : Getting scm site credentials for zip deployment:
"Deployment endpoint responded with status code 202"

Am i missing a setting or parameter in the deploy ?
```

If i check Azure it says that the webjob is "Pending Restart" and it
doesnt get out of that state ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to publish the Zip deployment in KUDU you need to  use credentials of web app publish profile file.
[image]

and Kudu has a set of rest Api to perform crud operations.
Here is the [github link](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API) to know more about the Kudu rest apis:

You can use the below set of code to perform the zip deployment:

````xml
az login -u <username>
az account set --subscription <subscription_name>
$username = "`$website"
$password = "pwd"
 #Note that the $username here should look like `SomeUserName`, and **not** `SomeSite\SomeUserName`
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username, $password)))
$userAgent = "powershell/1.0" ```


 #call the zipdeploy API (which uses POST)
 $apiUrl = "https://{sitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy"
 $filePath = "C:\Temp\books.zip"
 Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method POST -InFile $filePath -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
````

In general for any changes in configuration or updates, web app request you to perform a restart operation to apply those changes. As you mentioned in the error message webjob returned a status code "202"(Accepted) Since the webjob does not received any confirmation about the previous operation got succeeded or not, that is the reason  why your webjob status is showing as "**pending restart**".

I would suggest you to stop and start the webjob manually and try performing the deployment operation again.

Answer (score 0):

For me RestMethod does not work.

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod `
    -Uri $uri `
    -ContentType "application/zip" `
    -Method "PUT" `
    -Headers @{ 
        Authorization         = $basic
        "Content-Disposition" = "attachment; filename=$($zippedArtifact.Name)"
    } `
    -UserAgent "PowerShell $($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString())" `
    -InFile $artifact
```

But the WebRequest:

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -InFile $zippedArtifact -ContentType "application/zip" -Method Put
```

Also create a test webjob from the portal to check your valid uri. For me was really different than default ones in manuals.